# Ubuntu 14.04LTS lost LAN after lastest update at May 13 2016

Tags: 14.04, networking

My ubuntu 14.04LTS desktop lost LAN connection after the latest update at May 13. It worked okay last night and installed the latest updates successfully. 
I find it got no LAN connection today when powered on. There is no network icon. 
The network setting said the network service is not compatible

My hardware:
CPU : AMD Athlon II X2 250 processor
Graphic AMD RS880
RAM : 4GB
LAN chip : 8169

I am using ubuntu 14.04LTS 64bit version.

I would like to know how I can roll back to the version that before the latest update 
or 
how I can fix this problem.

Thanks!

Li.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, same here. eth0 and wlan0 were missing when ifconfig was run. ifconfig -a did show both of those.

**The fix**:

1. Add following to /etc/network/interfaces:

> ```
> auto eth0
> iface eth0 inet DHCP
> ```

This should enable the wired Ethernet for you, and hopefully that should connect you to the Internet.

2. Check for software updates. There are network related fixes offered.
3. Manually run: `sudo NetworkManager`. This shold get back your Wi-Fi now.

Hope this helps. Please confirm if this works, so others will know, too. Cheers!